# Explain how JavaScript evaluate this code

Tags: javascript

`(true + false) > 2 + true;`

I run this on Chrome console debugger and the result is false.

But,

```
true + false = 1
1 > 2 = false
false + true = 1
```

Can someone explain why the answer is false?

Comment: `+` has precedece over `>`

Comment: Funny how many different questions are flagged as duplicate faster than I can click and the one which has the exact same question answered already, does not.

Answer (score 5):

`>` (greater than) has operator precedence 11, whereas `+` has operator precedence 12. [See MDN for a table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence). So:

```
(true + false) > 2 + true;
```

is equivalent to

```
(true + false) > (2 + true);
(1) > (2 + true);
(1) > (3);
1 > 3
false
```

Comment: Thanks, I overlooked on the operator precedence

Answer (score 2):

Addition has higher precedence than greater than operator. Therefore,

```
(true + false) > 2 + true
```

will proceed as

```
true + false = 1
2 + true = 3
1 > 3
```

and result 'false'.

You can write

```
((true + false) > 2) + true;
```

to achieved your original goal.

For reference you can check precedence order [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

Answer (score 0):

Because the two additions are evaluated before the greater than operation due to JS operator precedence. Look at it like this:

```
(true + false) > (2 + true);
```

That's essentially what's going on, and if you work out the parentheses:

```
(1 + 0) > (2 + 1)
1 > 3
```

You can see it's `false`.